# Use SQL output as the input, and iterate multiple times (Snowflake)

Tags: sql, loops, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to iterate a SQL statement below (Fig A), where I want to feed the output 'COMPONENT' (there could be multiple results) back into the original query as PARTNO.  I have managed to do this one time using a sub-query as below, but would like to iterate a limited number of times (max 10) if possible.

Is there a simple way to do this in Snowflake?

```
    --SIMPLE QUERY
    SELECT COMPONENT
    FROM "table"
    WHERE PARTNO IN('THING_1')
    AND ITS_TYPE IN('RED','BLUE')

    ; 

    --WITH SUB-QUERY
    SELECT COMPONENT,PARTNO,ITS_TYPE
    FROM "table"
    WHERE PARTNO IN 
    (
    SELECT COMPONENT
    FROM "table"
    WHERE PARTNO IN('THING_1')
    AND ITS_TYPE IN('RED','BLUE')
    )
    AND ITS_TYPE IN('RED','BLUE')
```

Comment: Mark, Have you tried `limit 10` to have only 10 results for sub query?

Comment: The sub-query is only performing one iteration.  I am wanting the iteration to loop 10 times.   In theory, I believe I could place 9 nested sub-queries inside each other, but was hoping there was a more elegant solution.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really be helpful.  I'm baffled on what you want to "iterate".  An explanation of what the code is supposed to be doing would also be very helpful.

Comment: Apologies, I'm trying to avoid using actual data as it's work related.  If I query 'Apple' and it results in 'Pear' and 'Banana',   I then want 'Pear' and 'Banana' to be fed back in as the input (but also reported as outputs in the final result) and this process to be repeated for 10 cycles.   Hope that helps provide the logic I require.

Comment: So is there a parent-child relationship between COMPONENT and PARTNO? Your second query is looking up PARTNO in a list of COMPONENT. More information about the tables and data in question is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to build a hierarchical tree of parts and components.
What you are looking for is recursive CTEs :https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/queries-cte.html#recursive-ctes-and-hierarchical-data

Comment: Morning Jose, this is exactly what I am doing but am somewhat lost as I'm still learning SQL.  My parts and their components are only contained in two columns.  PTNO and CMPNT_PTNO.  Therefore to go one level lower, I need to feed the result of CMPNT_PTNO from the first iteration back into PTNO to get the next recursion...and continue until there are no further recursions.  Would you be able to provide a basic SQL that would do this for multiple recursions as a starter, and I can progress it from there

Comment: There is an example of a recursive CTE query in the documentation I provided: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/queries-cte.html#recursive-cte-with-indented-output
If you are learning SQL I believe this is a good situation to do so. You can share here the DDL of both your tables and the SQL you produce and I can take a look if you cannot make sense of it.